# Unable to run the script in different browser at the same time in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();


    //Chrome
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","‪F:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    //WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();


    //IE
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","‪F:\\drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://facebook.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("ssss@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("123r45");
    driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_x")).click();
    }

}
```

The above code is written to automate facebook in firefox,chrome,ie but only in ff the script is working fine but not in chrome and ie

Comment: What doesn't work for you in IE or Chrome? Stack trace, please.

Also, think twice about posting credentials in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You can try this, put the installer .exe inside the source folder of your project. For me its working fine, I have tried it with chrome.

```
//For Chrome
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

//For IE
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```